# how can I control the reconnect in node.js mqtt library

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am using the [node.js mqtt library](https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js/) to connect a internet mqtt service

```
var name = '/#';
var mqttclient = mqtt.createClient(1883, service.getHost(),{username:"" ,password: service.getKey() });
mqttclient.on('connect', function onConnect(){
   winston.info('MQTT Connected'.green, '/'+service.getPattern()+name);
   mqttclient.subscribe('/'+service.getPattern()+name);
   mqttclient.on('message', handleMessage);
}); 

 mqttclient.on('disconnect', onConnect);
 mqttclient.on('close', onClose);
 mqttclient.on('error', onError);

 function onDisconnect(packet){
        winston.info('MQTT MONITOR disconnect!'+packet);            
 }

 function onClose(packet){
        winston.info('MQTT MONITOR close!'+packet); 
 }

 function onError(err){
        winston.error('MQTT MONITORerror!'+err);        
 }
```

when my internet connection disconnects or authentication username/password are wrong,  mqtt library will emit the close event, as long as mqtt.end(), this event will be continuously triggered.

```
2013-12-07T18:36:53.835Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:36:54.835Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:36:55.832Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:36:56.833Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:36:57.831Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:36:58.847Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:36:59.842Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:37:00.833Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:37:01.832Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
2013-12-07T18:37:02.847Z - info: MQTT MONITOR close!false
```

it seems to me the mqtt close callback can't tell me what kind of error is happening, such as authentication error or host can't reach error.

Moreover, I assume there is a reconnect strategy. how can I control this reconnect strategy in mqtt code?

Comment: Just as a side note, topics do not need to start with '/'. In fact it adds a extra level to the topic tree that is not needed. Subscribing to '/#' is different to '#'

Answer (score 0):

Look at your broker log to see clues for this behaviour.

In MQTT protocol `keepalive` value defines the rate to send a ping message to the broker.

Also use different `clientid` when connecting various clients to the same broker.